# Best way to change the blog page post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, blog-page

what is the best way to change the wordpress blog page post type. by default it fetches the posts with post type  is equal to posts but how we can change to to lets say posts type is equal to blog.
One way is to add the costume query on the index.php page and selecting the specific post type.
Is there any other effective way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may edit the query using the [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action. You can do something like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse_218948_search_filter');

function wpse_218948_search_filter(){
   if( is_page('blog') /* or whatever page it is */ && $query->is_main_query() ){
      $query->set('post_type', 'blog'); # query post type "blog"
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 ); # display all posts
   }
}
```

Comment: hi i have modified you code accourding to my reeuirement it is working fine but one issue it is only showing 1 post

Comment: but i have 4 posts in my blog

Comment: Add `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );` to display all posts. Updating my answer.